# Lower bounds for the number of bases of a paving matroid

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, matroid-theory

Let $M$ be a paving matroid with $m$ elements and rank $n$. Is there any lower bound for the number of bases of $M$? There is an upper bound for the number of hyperplanes (see [here](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/files/75493302/20170920_Pol.pdf), page 97) but since not all hyperplanes are $n$-subsets in paving matroids, it is not clear whether this upper bound is helpful to find a bound for the number of bases.

Comment: A general version of this question had been asked a while ago. You may want to look at the answers and comments there. https://mathoverflow.net/q/212411/22051